# How do I stop apps trying to use a dial-up connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, dial-up

Every now and again, I might have to use a dial-up internet connection via another tethered phone, i.e. Bluetooth connection to the GPRS modem. Now I am back on 'ops normal', i.e. using a shared internet connection on my own phone, or on my 3G stick, but some apps, especially IE9, keep popping up a 'dialup connection' dialogue, which I cannot dismiss enough times ever, to make to stay away.

How can I tell these idiot applications that I no longer need a dial-up connection?

Comment: It has been a long time since I used dial-up, but generally it seemed that it was the system doing that, on the applications request. In the internet options, connections, there are various things that can control that. How are they all set? including in the lan settings (auto) stuff?  Or , if it is not system specific, then a piece of software that was used for that connection type, that information you did not say. Like whos dialup connection dialog?  Also what is the possibility that it does that when your primary connection is lost? It might be possible to temp disable a service too.

Comment: in the internet settings, remove the checkbox which says "dial a connection".

Comment: use "never dial a connection"...

Answer (score 1):

I use Bluetooth tethering occasionally, too. Here's how to make sure that connection is established only manually in Windows 7:

1. Open Start menu
2. Type `int opt` - the top result will be `Internet Options`, open it
3. Swithc to `Connections` tab
4. Make sure that `Never dial a connection` is selected in the group of radio buttons under the list of connections
5. Click `OK`

[image]